# How to keep the bar width unchanged when scroll the pan?

Tags: android, achartengine

I have completed one figure with achartengine and I want to draw a combined chart which including one bar chart. And I have set the width of bars and the spacing betweent bars. BUt when I scroll pan, I found that the width of bars are not the same. Could somebody help me? I want to set the width all the same when scroll the pan. Thank you very much!

```
renderer.setBarSpacing(0.5);
renderer.setBarWidth(30000000);
```

Comment: Maybe you can post a screenshot?

Comment: I have no permission to upload any figures. Could you tell me you e-mail, so I can send the screenshots to you. My e-mail is jing.mao@intel.com. Thank you very much!

Comment: Please try again now, you will probably have the permission.